# How to fetch these input fields with dynamic ids

Tags: java, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a webpage where there are few text fields to be filled up with some values using Selenium WebDriver. But I'm unable to fetch these items using the APIs provided in selenium framwework because the IDs are changing dynamically.

For example one of the text fields has the following ID

```
<input id="order_unit_line_rate_806099_unit_price" type="text" value="" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Platform Fee / / Price" size="10" onchange="javascript:numberFormatValid('order_unit_line_rate_806099_unit_price', parseI18nNumber($('order_unit_line_rate_806099_unit_price').value, ',', '.'), 5, '.');" name="order_unit_line_rate[806099][unit_price]">
```

where the digits 806099 which is a part of the id varies for every new page and every new text box. I didn't have any luck by using the findElements(By.id()) API.

can someone please suggest any approach for identifying these elements.

I'm using eclipse as the editor, java as the client driver and selenium webDriver as the automation framework.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: The same thing happens when i try to use findElement.(By.name()); because the name also contains the 6 digits number. \n Is there anyway where i can use a regular expression here. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findElementsByTagName and then loop over each returned element, checking its ID versus your regular expression:

```
public static WebElement findElementByRegexId(FindsByTagName ctx, String tagName, String regex) {
    List<WebElement> l = ctx.findElementsByTagName(tagName);
    for (WebElement e : l) {
        if (e.getAttribute("id").matches(regex)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response :) .. Will try this and get back to you on the observations :)

Comment: that was a perrrrrfect answer what i was looking for. Thanks a million for that response :).

Answer (score 0):

The selenium API also allows you to pass XPath locators, so you can probably try something like

```
findElements(By.xpath("//input[@uniqueattr=\"Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Platform Fee / / Price\"]"));
```

See [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#by-xpath) for more details.

Comment: @Didlier : thanks for the response buddy :) .. Will try this and get back to you on the observations :)

Comment: @Didler : this is the error i got using this. 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@uniqueattr=\"Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Platform Fee / / Price\"]"}

Comment: I just tried in Selenium IDE and it seems to work, try doing the same to validate the proposed XPath. Also, you should pay attention to the quotes and escaping. Maybe you can try with single quotes like this: `findElements(By.xpath("//input[@uniqueattr='Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Platform Fee / / Price']"));`. The problem with such XPath (containing user-friendly labels) is that it is very error-prone. Wouldn't it be possible to add a technical attribute, or maybe use the class attribute? Maybe the problem is that `uniqueattr` is not a standard attribute.

Comment: you are right, @unique is not a standard attribute, its a custom added attrib by our dev team and i found out that there is no API to do a get() on it :( ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expression you can use below solution

```
//input[contains(@name, 'order_unit_line_rate')]
```

Comment: @Thanks Rohit, but there are many more elements with the same starting string, like checkboxes. The textboxes which i need to populate are having the names "order_unit_line_rate[806099][unit_price]" or "order_unit_line_rate[806099][limit_price]" . so i need to check for that part of the string which follows the 6 digit number. Any comments on this

Comment: You can use unit_price OR limit_Price text..Is this will work for you??

Comment: I tried all these Rohit, :( but it days Unable to find the locator :(.i tried ur syntax with @uniqueattr also, but no luck again :( .. ANy more suggestions ?